# Create spinner programmatically from array in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm all new to Android and I'm trying to create a spinner programatically and feeding it with data from an array when i tapped on button

when i tapped on my first button then button below i want to show courtliest with the help of SpinnerList

when i tapped on my second button then button below i want to show moviesList with the help of SpinnerList please help me some one

### xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Button1Action"
        android:text="CountiesList"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Button2Action"
        android:text="MoviesList"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### activity:-

```
public class spinnerListProgramatically extends AppCompatActivity{

    String [] countriesList = {"india","usa","england"
    };

    String [] moviesList = {"fury","300 rise of an empire","troy"
    };

    Spinner spinner;
    LinearLayout parentLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinnerlist_runtime);

        parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    }

    public void Button1Action(View view){

        //Initializing imageView
        spinner = new Spinner(this);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        parentLayout.addView(spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    public void Button2Action(View view){



    }
}
```

Comment: suggestion : add spinner in xml and replace array in adapter on button change.

Comment: Can u tell me with some code I am very new

Comment: @Ramakrishna Refer here: - http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-spinner/

Answer (score 2):

Try this code
**XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Button1Action"
            android:text="CountiesList"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Button2Action"
            android:text="MoviesList"/>
    <Spinner
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1">

    </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**ACTIVITY:**

```
public class spinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    String [] countriesList = {"india","usa","england"
    };

    String [] moviesList = {"fury","300 rise of an empire","troy"
    };

    Spinner spinner;
    LinearLayout parentLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinnerlist_runtime);
        spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    }

    public void Button1Action(View view){


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    public void Button2Action(View view){

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, moviesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place all your spinners at their respective positions in the XML file but set their visibility to `gone`. When the button is clicked, make their visibility as `visible` again:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Button1Action"
    android:text="CountiesList"/>

<Spinner
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below:"@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


    <!--Write all the spinner properties here-->
</Spinner>
```

Then, in the java class, in the `Button1Action`, set it's visibility to visible:

```
public void Button1Action(View view){

    //Initializing imageView
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    parentLayout.addView(spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: hi @user5038993 i have dought

Comment: what is the doubt?

Comment: I want to show spinner list below of button with 5 dp difference when we tapped on button

Comment: I hope u understand?

Comment: try the updated code. And yes, replace ``LinearLayout` by `RelativeLayout`

Comment: can u update please i am not undesratnd how to do that